# Descending sort by value of a Hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

My input hash: `h = { "a" => 20, "b" => 30, "c" => 10 }`

Ascending sort: `h.sort {|a,b| a[1]<=>b[1]}   #=> [["c", 10], ["a", 20], ["b", 30]]`

But, I need `[["b", 30], ["a", 20], ["c", 10]]`

How is can we make it work the other way around, what does `<=>` mean?

Answer (score 203, accepted):

You can have it cleaner, clearer and faster, all at once! Like this:

```
h.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
```

I benchmarked timings on 3000 iterations of sorting a 1000-element hash with random values, and got these times:

```
h.sort {|x,y| -(x[1]<=>y[1])} -- 16.7s
h.sort {|x,y| y[1] <=> x[1]} -- 12.3s
h.sort_by {|k,v| -v} -- 5.9s
h.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse -- 3.7
```

Comment: Visually this is cleaner but it causes an extra traversal of the collection to reverse it.

Comment: @glennmcdonald can you please tell me how can one calculate the timings for each call in ruby ?

Comment: I found out how to calculate the time wrt each call. Here's a sample link:- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort

Comment: What about `h.sort_by(&:last).reverse`? Any times on that?

Comment: Which Ruby version?

Comment: @TamzinBlake: I really dont think `sort_by` mutates the hash. What did you mean exactly?

Comment: Nice catch! `.sort_by!` mutates the hash, `.sort_by` does not.

Comment: I found a feature requirement for `sort_by`, to support sorting in descending order, open at https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12648 wherein all the proposed solutions here  can be seen to be suggested.

Answer (score 12):

```
h.sort {|a,b| b[1]<=>a[1]}
```

Comment: I've downvoted this comment, not because the answer is wrong, but because you don't explain why this is the correct answer. The questioner even asked specifically what "<=>" means - so (s)he's clearly after some explanation of how this all works. It's a good idea to help out that way :)

Comment: PS: see the Stack Overflow review policy on meta for more: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74194/how-to-review-can-we-agree-on-a-review-policy

Answer (score 12):

Super simple: `h.sort_by { |k, v| -v }`

Answer (score 10):

`<=>` compares the two operands, returning -1 if the first is lower, 0 if they're equal and 1 if the first is higher. This means that you can just do `-(a[1]<=>b[1])` to reverse the order.

Comment: I always prefer seeing it written with the "a" and "b" elements swapped, rather than negating the result. With them swapped I only have to look at their order to see they're backwards to know it's reversed. When the value of `<=>` is negated I still have to look at the actual comparison to know what is going on. It's a minor point but something I'm aware of because I can feel my brain have to do the second check after doing a "What!?"

Comment: @Greg: I definitely see why you'd prefer it the other way. I'm the opposite: To my scanning eyes, `b[1]<=>a[1]` looks hella like `a[1]<=>b[1]` and I feel a need to stop and check, whereas the negation makes it immediately obvious that we're doing a reverse sort.

Comment: I understand your point too. Either way of doing it still requires a careful look at the values being compared. Maybe we need a different operator - `>=<` for reverse order? Nah, that'd be just as bad. It's the entire construct, but I prefer `<=>` over a more verbose approach where we'd have to call some method names.