# Getting an array of keys from a hash ordered by the hash's values

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting, hashmap

I have a hash which is something like this

```
{"red" => 3, "blue" => 1, "yellow" => 3, "green" => 1, "black" => 4}
```

I want to sort and display the top three colors in the order of the hash's values i.e

```
["black", "red", "yellow"]
```

I tried to do something like `sort_by { |x,y| h[x] <=> h[y] }` and `max_by { |x,y| h[x] }`, but I only get `["black"]`. How do you get the top three occurrences?

Comment: See answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264133/descending-sort-by-value-of-a-hash-in-ruby

Answer (score 8):

As variant:

```
h = {"green"=>1, "red"=>3, "yellow"=>3, "blue"=>1, "black"=>4}
h.sort_by{ |color, n| -n }.map(&:first).take(3) #=> ["black", "red", "yellow"]
```

Comment: I like the use of `sort_by`. A bit more clever than my solution.

Comment: You could also `.map(&:first).take(3)` to cut down on the block noise.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way to do it.

```
colors = {"red"=>3, "blue"=>1, "yellow"=>3, "green"=>1, "black"=>4}
colors.sort { |a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] }.map { |a| a[0] }.take(3)
```

Comment: Does that gel with *Ruby hashes are unordered*?

Comment: Yes, sort will actually return an array of arrays. So yes.

Comment: I see, that makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: b[1] <=> a[1] is pretty perl style for reverse sort, anyway, I like it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to do it.

```
sortedColours = colours.keys
 .sort {|keyA, keyB| colours[keyB] - colours[keyA] }
```

[Riddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/5265d).

If you want the top 3, just slice off the first 3.

```
firstThreeColours = sortedColours[0,3]
```

Comment: `.take(3)` will give you first 3 elements.

Comment: @xdazz Is that recommended over `[0,3]` ?