# Sorting Hash by value

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I want to sort my has by value.I am tried to sort my hash this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4264133/descending-sort-by-value-of-a-hash-in-ruby) and it does not work, I don't know why.
This is my code:

```
test="neki text sa recima neki sa i jos neki aa"
mapa=Hash.new(0)
test.split(" ").each do |rec|
    mapa[rec]+=1
end

mapa.sort_by {|a,b| b}.reverse

mapa.each do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} #{value}" 
end
```

the output is :

```
neki 3
text 1
sa 2
recima 1
i 1
jos 1
aa 1
```

It doesn't do anything to the HASH :/
Can someone explain to me why it does not work?

if you give me a MINUS please explain in the comment what I did to deserve it so I know where to improve. :)

Comment: Be careful using `sort_by` with simple objects. It adds overhead and can slow the actual sort process. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2651028/128421 and [the `sort_by` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) for a good description and a comparison along with the Wikipedia article on "[Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Enumerable#sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) never promised to sort the enumerable *inplace*. It *returns* the result:

```
puts mapa.sort_by {|a,b| -b}
#⇒ sorted
```

or, in more idiomatic manner:

```
mapa.sort_by(&:last).reverse.each do |k, v|
  puts ...
end
```

Please note, that when examining the output in `irb`, the order might not correspond to the real order of elements in a hash, since `irb` (with print formatters installed) has it’s own ideas on how to output hashes.

Comment: Thank you. So I have to just say mapa = mapa.sort_by {|a,b| b}.reverse .
I was didnt know it returns a value, was thinking it changes the HASH.

Comment: Well, yes. Basically in ruby all functions that _mutate_ an object, are by convention called having a trailing bang: `sort_by!` would mutate the hash itself (if existed.)

Comment: mudsie, where would you put `mapa.max_by(mapa.size, &:last).to_h #=>  {:neki=>3, :sa=>2, :i=>1, :aa=>1, :jos=>1, :text=>1, :recima=>1} ` in the idomatic order?

Comment: @CarySwoveland since idiomatic ruby is to be represented by hash `{way_of_solution => ->() {} }`, it is unordered in ruby :) Well, joking aside, I like `max_by` more than mine `sort_by`.